# How to work with radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am having two radio button plan a, plane b and i ant that when i click on plane a then check box android apps,web apps checked and texbox smart card enable and if i click plane b then all check box should be  checked and all text box should be enable

```
    <p class="contact">
<input type="radio" name="PlanA"id="PlanA"value="A"><label for="PlanA"><span style="font-weight:bold">PlanA</span></label><br>
<input name="PlanA" type="hidden" value=0 />
</p>

<p class="contact">
<input type="radio" name="PlanB"id="PlanB"value="B"><label for="PlanB"><span style="font-weight:bold">PlanB</span></label><br>
<input name="PlanB" type="hidden" value=0 />
</p>

<p class="contact">
 <input type="checkbox" name="AndroidApps" id="smartphone" value=1><label for="AndroidApps"><span style="font-weight:bold">AndroidApps</span></label><br>
 <input name="AndroidApps" type="hidden" value=0 />
</p>

<p class="contact">
<input type="checkbox" name="WebApps" id="mobweb" value=1><label for="WebApps"><span style="font-weight:bold">WebApps</span></label><br>
<input name="WebApps" type="hidden" value=0 />
            </p>

<p class="contact"><label for="SmartCard"><span style="font-weight:bold">SmartCard</span></label>
<input type="text" name="SmartCard"id="scard"disabled="disabled" required size="45"  >
</p>

<p class="contact"><label for="comment"><span style="font-weight:bold">EmailService</span></label>
<input type=email name="emailid"id="emailid"disabled="disabled" required size="45"  >
</p>

<p class="contact"><label for="comment"><span style="font-weight:bold">SmsService</span></label>

<input type=tel name="mobnum"id="mobnum"disabled="disabled"  required onKeyUp="isValidChar(this.value);" size="45">
</p>
```

i tried  here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#PlanA').on('change',function(e) {
        console.log("dfsd");
       $("#mobweb,#smartphone,#smartcard").prop("checked",this.checked);
         $("#scard").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#PlanB').on('change',function(e) {
        console.log("dfsd");
       $("#mobweb,#smartphone,#smartcard,#email,#sms").prop("checked",this.checked);
        $("#emailid").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
        $("#mobnum").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
          $("#scard").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

How Can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your javascript code? Wanna see what you tried

Comment: when i am trying then if i click on any one radio button it work fine and then if i click another button then it does not unclick from that last

Comment: Your radio buttons are not linked, so it does not know that the selected one should be unclicked. Also, your code will not work because there's a space missing between name and id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#PlanA').on('change',function(e) {
        $('input:radio').not(this).attr('checked',false);
       $("#mobweb,#smartphone,#smartcard").prop("checked",this.checked);
        $("#emailid").prop("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
        $("#mobnum").prop("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
         $("#scard").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });

    $('#PlanB').on('change',function(e) {
      $('input:radio').not(this).attr('checked',false); $("#mobweb,#smartphone,#smartcard,#email,#sms").prop("checked",this.checked);
        $("#emailid").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
        $("#mobnum").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
          $("#scard").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qf883/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

The `'name' attribute` of all the radio buttons in your case should be same but `id` can be different. All radios with same name are in a group called radio group. They will work as they want you to.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to group your radios with same name.

Try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.contact').on('change', ':radio', function(e) {
     if(this.id === "PlanA"){
       $("#mobweb,#smartphone,#smartcard").prop("checked", this.checked);
       $("#scard").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
     } else if(this.id === "PlanB"){
       $(':checkebox').prop("checked", this.checked);
       $('[type=text], [type=email], [type=tel]').prop("disabled", !this.checked);
     }
   });
 });
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H29NJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Check JSFiddle for this  below will help to see actually

jsfiddle.net/rohanppatil/TTknF/8/